# An error occurred during local report processing

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I have a reportViewer that I want to print, and it's working in my developing PC but when I deploy it to my client it says:
`An error occurredd during local report processing` .

My code is as follows:

```
        try
        {
            ReportParameter[] param = new ReportParameter[12];
            param[0] = new ReportParameter("p1", P1);
            param[1] = new ReportParameter("p2", P2);
            param[2] = new ReportParameter("p3", " ");
            param[3] = new ReportParameter("p4", " ");
            param[4] = new ReportParameter("p4", " ");
            param[5] = new ReportParameter("p5", " ");
            param[6] = new ReportParameter("p6", " ");
            param[7] = new ReportParameter("p7", " ");
            param[8] = new ReportParameter("p8", " ");
            param[9] = new ReportParameter("p9", " ");
            param[10] = new ReportParameter("p10", " ");
            param[11] = new ReportParameter("p11", P11);
            reportViewer1.Reset();
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ReportPath"].ToString();//Application.StartupPath + "\\rptReport.rdlc";

            reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(param);

            Export(reportViewer1.LocalReport);
            Print();
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            this.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["debug"].ToString()) == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: maybe you should output the content of ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ReportPath"] in your error messagebox to get more information about what's happening ...

Comment: @PrfctByDsgn : Why to do so ?
btw, all permisions are enabled .

Comment: just to make sure the path is set correctly on your client's pc ...

Comment: I printed it out, and the path is correct.
Also, just to make sure that i can access the file, i opened it with Stream and it opened fine.

I don't know where is the problem :(

Comment: Here it's my reportviewer file:
[reportViewerFile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B49fhAdW4O1vOHVvQlFHdW9JRmc/view?usp=sharing)